# Authenticating Domain Users with System.DirectoryServices

Tags: .net, authentication, directoryservices

Given a username and a password for a domain user, what would be the best way to authenticate that user programatically?

Answer (score 17):

It appears that .NET 3.5 added a new namespace to deal with this issue - System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. Code sample is below:

```
Private Function ValidateExternalUser(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
    Using context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _defaultDomain)
        Return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate)
    End Using
End Function
```

The namespace also seems to provide a lot of methods for manipulating a domain account (changing passwords, expiring passwords, etc).

Answer (score 9):

You can use some hacks to **authenticate** only.

```
Try
    Dim directoryEntry as New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DomainController:389/dc=domain,dc=suffix", "username", "password")
    Dim temp as Object = directoryEntry.NativeObject
    return true
Catch
    return false
End Try
```

If the user is not valid, the directory entry NativeObject cannot be accessed and throws an exception.  While this isn't the most efficient way (exceptions are evil, blah blah blah), it's quick and painless.  This also has the super-cool advantage of working with all LDAP servers, not just AD.

Comment: you should never catch ALL exceptions like that...  COMException is what will be thrown when you can't access the LDAP server so that is what you would be catching.