# Global.asax vs IhttpHandler for webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, global-asax

I am currently using a custom IHttpHandler class for parsing requests and sending back responses. Are there any advantages to using any of the global.asax methods as well?

Comment: Which global.asax methods -- it isn't even a class . . .

Comment: I was looking at the BeginRequest method.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using the Global.asax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean [HttpApplication events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events.aspx) vs IHttpHandler, they're not really comparable.

HttpApplication events are usually used from [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx)s for cross-cutting concerns that apply (in principle) to all HTTP requests.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769432/ihttphandler-vs-ihttpmodule) explains the differences between IHttpModule and IHttpHandler

Comment: Pretty good article, but I still don't fully understand if there is any advantage to putting certain aspects of my web service in an httpmodule. I'm thinking in terms of performance.

Comment: @chobo: performance has nothing to do here. It's like asking whether it's faster to use a hammer or a screwdriver: they're different tools for different things.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly are you trying to do?

`IHttpHandler` is useful for when you want precise control over the HTTP request / response, however typically this is when you are developing a framework - most of the time the same thing can be achieved elsewhere.

`IHttpHandler` certainly isn't commonly used for web services, for that you should look into either using [WCF](http://blog.mstern.at/index.php?/archives/64-Creating-a-WCF-web-service-in-C-using-Visual-Studio-2008.html), or using [ASP.Net web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0z6a33%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (if you are targeting the .Net 2.0 framework where WCF is  not available).  Using a dedicated web services toolset will make it much easier to expose your service in a consistent way (via SOAP, JSON etc...)

I'm not quite sure how global.asax comes into it - global.asax is, well... **global**.  Anything that you do here will apply to the entire web application, so in particular any handling of requests that you do here will apply to **all** requests that reach your application.  This isn't the place that you should be implementing web serivces.

Comment: I initially tried using WCF, but it was too much of a learning curve to make it work with POST'ed XML requests, so I used a handler. What I was getting at in my post was is there any performance advantage of using the global.asax (or httpmodules) for certain parts of a web service, like custom authentication and checking the request origin? Does it make any difference?