# Flushing basic authentication on ASP site

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I have an intranet application that requires basic authentication against active directory using NT challenge/response.

When a cookie expires, I would like to "flush" (for lack of a better term) that authentication, redirect them to a non-protected page and force the user to re-authenticate should they want to re-access the protected page.

How is this done?  I can't seem to figure it out.

Using ASP classic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact science, but ive used the following in the past:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536979.aspx

Basic Example in JS:

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache')
```

Not sure what the browser support is like in non-IE browsers though, there is a similar question that should work in all browsers:

[Is there a browser equivalent to IE's ClearAuthenticationCache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326/is-there-a-browser-equivalent-to-ies-clearauthenticationcache)