# Clear browser cache programatically (delete Active Logins with JS)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

How to clear browser cache (Active Logins).

In IE we can delete it with

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', false);
```

but this doesn't work in firefox or chrome.

I need for changing client certificate without clearing Active Logins via browser interface.

Comment: Did not check but FYI [link](http://patabugen.co.uk/2013/12/09/httpauth-logout-in-chrome-firefox-and-ie-with-jquery/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326/is-there-a-browser-equivalent-to-ies-clearauthenticationcache